# extract more than one similar pattern string from one string using regex in perl

Tags: string, perl, extract

Need your help how to extract more than one similar string from one string using Regex in Perl

This is source string :

> Sat Feb 16 23:56:30 ICT 2013 - wulan321~ sw dadan complain cant acces internet   HP : Samsung galaxy S3  offer :  Offer and VAS Active    Type    Active Since  Expiry Date    Remaining    More     **AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data500MB_30D    Regular SOC    2/16/2013 4:19:29 PM**        0    AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data500MB_30D    **AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data1.2GB_30D    Regular SOC    2/16/2013 11:47:05 PM**      0    AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data1.2GB_30D      CM : reff gpnblo  apn : intern et username : dikosongkan paswword : dikosongkan  done

My output expectation is :

```
AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data500MB_30D 2/16/2013 4:19:29 PM
AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data1.2GB_30D 2/16/2013 11:47:05 PM
```

I already done some works with perl :

```
if ($string =~ /([Additional.*|A ?O.*])+(AO_.+?)+[\t*?| *?]Regular SOC[\t*?| *?](.+?[A|P] ?M)/) 
{
    print "$2 $3\n";
}
```

But the output only captured the first occur string:

```
AO_MDS_PDMA_Pre/Post_Data500MB_30D 2/16/2013 4:19:29 PM
```

Looking forward for the guidance guys

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop and the `g` flag:

```
while ($string =~ /REGEX-HERE/g) 
{
    print "$2 $3\n";
}
```